# Running Timer, Stopwatch, and Compass example on Glass doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I ran the timer, stopwatch, and compass example here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#for_android_beginners

However, the application builds but doesn't run.  This is all I can get in logcat:

```
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] ------------------------------
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] Android Launch!
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] Performing sync
[2013-11-19 15:58:21 - CompassMenuActivity] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-11-19 15:58:23 - CompassMenuActivity] Uploading CompassMenuActivity.apk onto device '0***************0C'
[2013-11-19 15:58:23 - CompassMenuActivity] Installing CompassMenuActivity.apk...
[2013-11-19 15:58:24 - CompassMenuActivity] Success!
[2013-11-19 15:58:24 - CompassMenuActivity] /CompassMenuActivity/bin/CompassMenuActivity.apk installed on device
[2013-11-19 15:58:24 - CompassMenuActivity] Done!
```

I'm using

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: You can install via ADB, MyGlass app or compile the code and then say "OK, Google" and run them that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "Run as" menu in Eclipse will only install the APK on the device but won't run it, because none of the application components in the manifest have `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Instead, after the APK is installed, you can use the voice trigger on Glass to start it. For example, say "ok glass, show a compass" for the Compass sample. This will start the `CompassService` service that publishes the live card to the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to use voice trigger or touch menu to launch, you can also use adb command to launch the service, this will save some time, because it gets kind of old to manually navigate to launch the app.

```
adb shell am startservice com.google.android.glass.compass/com.google.android.glass.sample.compass.CompassService 
adb shell am startservice com.google.android.glass.timer/com.google.android.glass.sample.timer.TimerService
adb shell am startservice com.google.android.glass.stopwatch/com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch.StopwatchService:
```

or

```
adb shell am startservice <name of service>
adb shell am start <name of activity>
```

Comment: Documentation says, "To start the sample, say "ok glass, start a stopwatch" from the Glass clock screen or use the touch menu.", I ran, but nothing is happening, i have build and ran from android studio. Any help?

Comment: W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10025
11-21 22:52:13.642    2186-2353/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch/.MenuActivity } from null (pid=25467, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10025,              I am getting following error.

Comment: Are you certain the sample app was installed successfully?

Comment: Yes, everything was installed successfully, but XE11 update was not there, that was a reason. I left the device plugin and updated XE11, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have XE11 update, otherwise it wont' work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the debug configuration. The second section should have a launch activity option. Since you don't have a default (because it is triggered by the voice intent) you can select one from the project manually. this will then auto launch the main activity when you debug the application.