# GDK Sample installed but cannot launch

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I tried running a sample project from the GDK. I followed the instructions exactly as desrcibed [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZSLKtpgQkc).

The apk is installed bu the following warning also appears:

```
[2013-11-26 15:38:02 - Stopwatch] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-11-26 15:38:02 - Stopwatch] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

The only issue is that although the apk is installed i cannot launch the sample! Is there any way to launch the sample using adb? Should i see the "start a stopwatch" (for example) in the list of available commands when i say "ok, glass"?

Comment: Please take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952915/google-glass-sample-apks

Comment: Or this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084787/running-timer-stopwatch-and-compass-example-on-glass-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your IDE's run configuration is misconfigured. If you would like to use the voice command to launch your GDK Glassware, you must configure your IDE to not launch any activity at the time of installation.

Here are some screen shots.

**Android Studio**

[image]

**Eclipse ADT**

[image]