# Can't run Stopwatch sample using android phone as an emulator

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am new in Glass development and as I don't have the Glass
I have installed Stopwatch sample using android phone as an emulator.
But the applicarion crashes when I try to run it on my phone.

Here are the changes that I did in `AndroidManifest.xml` using [this](https://github.com/blaind/gdk-stopwatch-sample/commit/26e9801af983b9fc931d6dfe5ce1fcb80766fd10) as a referance

```
>  <activity
>             android:name="com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch.MenuActivity"
>             android:label="@string/app_name"
>             android:theme="@style/MenuTheme"
>             android:enabled="true" >
>             
>              <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>           </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
```

I tried to follow also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084787/running-timer-stopwatch-and-compass-example-on-glass-doesnt-seem-to-work) link but I still can't see the applicarion running on my android device.

What other changes do I need to do?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: And when I write in console `adb shell am startservice com.google.android
.glass.sample.stopwatch/.StopwatchService` I get an alert on my phone `Unfortunately, StopWatch has stopped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to run the samples on an Android phone because they do not have the Glass system software installed, which the GDK is trying to access.

Currently the only way that you can run a GDK application is on a physical Glass device.